# addObserver() method, of observer pattern and object variable lifecycle/scope, Java

Tags: java, observer-pattern

when I use the method .addObserver() for example:

```
  class ExampleOne implements Observer {

  class ExampleTwo extends Observable {


  ExampleOne one = new ExampleOne();

  ExampleTwo two = new ExampleTwo();

  two.addObserver(one)
```

in this case, is the connection between instance objects "two" and "one" or the class.class like a static situation,  it looks to me like instance, but not sure, if this is a connection between observer and the observed then what happens if either "one" or "two" is garbage collected or goes out of scope?   does that destroy the observer setup.

example of this is when a server receives a String message from the client,  and the observer is used to notify when a new text message has arrived.  if one of the instance variables goes out of scope and is garbage collected then there will be no more notification when messages arrive because the system will be broken.  is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable` has a `vector` which **holds the reference** to all the observers that have been registered using the `addObserver()` method. So even if the observer goes out of scope the reference to it is still present in the observable and will **not be garbage collected**.

To garbage collect it call the `removeObserver` and then it will be garbage collected.

If `Observable` goes out of scope then yes, no notifications would be sent now to the observers. And the Observers can be garbage collected.

> in this case, is the connection between instance objects "two" and
>   "one" or the class.class like a static situation

Yes everything is happening on instances and no statics are involved here.

Answer (score -1):

Observable retains a reference to each observer added to it until explicitly removed.
So an Observer can become eligible for garbage collection only when Observable does.

There's no back reference from Observer to Observable unless introduced by your code. So keeping a reference to an Observer doesn't prevent Observable from garbage collection.

You can always look at Observable source code to see how it's done:

```
public synchronized void addObserver(Observer o) {
    if (o == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
if (!obs.contains(o)) {
    obs.addElement(o);
}
}
```

Where `obs` is a Vector, which keeps references to its elements.